# Getting stuck on "Downloading Javascript bundle 100.00%" in expo app

Tags: reactjs, expo, ios-simulator

Whenever I click 'run in iOS simulator' after running `expo start` in terminal, I'm getting stuck at a screen with "Downloading Javascript bundle 100.00%" in the app.

I'm creating a React native application and I tried all solutions including:

1. deleting Expo app
2. restarting simulator
3. erasing settings on simulator
4. rechecking code for bugs
5. Debug remote JS / stop remote debugging

See example of loading screen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzEdZ.png

Answer (score 1):

Delete your package-lock.json file, node_modules directory and then,
run npm cache clean -f.
Then run a new npm install as a regular user.
Finally, run an npm start again

Answer (score 0):

try clearing the cache with expo start -c

Comment: still no luck :(